# MS access Query pull 9 digit number from string

Tags: ms-access

I've been looking on google but cant quite find exactly what i need & using these sorts of functions is my weak spot. 
Basically, from an alphanumeric string in a table, I need to pull out any 9 digit numbers. they will always start with 0. The numbers won't have any breaks within them. 
I would also prefer to retrieve the 9 digits using a query. ie have the pulled number sit alone in a separate column. there will only be 1 9 digit number

I have the below, which pulls out the number, i just dont know how to limit the length with it as the string with have other things, like parts of addresses and whatnot.

```
PHONE: Mid([DESCRIPTION],InStrRev([DESCRIPTION]," ",InStr([DESCRIPTION],"0"))+1,InStr(InStr([DESCRIPTION],"0"),[DESCRIPTION]," ")-InStrRev([DESCRIPTION]," ",InStr([DESCRIPTION],"0")))
```

Comment: [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271). Sample data and expected result is much more useful than a textual description. Note: Sample data != real data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Split* for this:

```
Public Function StripNine(ByVal Text As String) As String

    Dim Words   As Variant
    Dim Index   As Integer
    Dim Result  As String

    Words = Split(Text, " ")
    For Index = LBound(Words) To UBound(Words)
        If Len(Words(Index)) = 9 Then
            If IsNumeric(Words(Index)) Then
                Result = Words(Index)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    StripNine = Result

End Function
```

This will run and return for an example like this:

```
s = "This is 1 message 00 with a 09-digit number 087654321 somewhere in the body"
? StripNine(s)
087654321
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `Mid()` function. Like this:

```
Mid("Test1String", 1, 4) 'Result = "Test"
Mid("Test2String", 5, 3) 'Result = "2St"
Mid("Test3String", 7, 2) 'Result = "tr"
```

And if you want to eliminate the blanks you can use:

```
Trim(" Test4 String ") 'Result = "Test4 String"
Replace(" Test5 String ", " ", "") 'Result = "Test5String"
```

**UPDATE:**

Try this:

```
Dim intPostion As Integer
Dim strResult As String

intPosition = InStr(YourString, 0) 'Search for the 0
strResult = Mid(YourString, intPosition, 9) 'Extract 9 digits
```

If you put this in a **loop** (so that **intPosition** checks the whole string) and check if **strResult** has only numeric numbers you should get your result.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i didn't explain very well, i need to pull only 9 digit numbers from a string, which is basically the body of an email, which will always be in different parts of the string. There will also be other numbers in the string, like house numbers or whatnot, so i cant just remove everything but the numbers

Comment: As I understand it you want only numbers where the length is 9? And this number is hidden between other numbers and strings. Do you have a sample? For better understanding. And the number starts always with a **0**?

Comment: Sorry, it is 10 digits not 9, but yes, always starts with a 0, they are phone numbers, which in my country start with 0. Also i'm happy to accept something that brings up any 10 digit number, regardless of the starting digit



"Please Contact Ryan masterson from Westvanmobile service located in 14 Napoleon way vanmont with regards to “Billing and payments” enquiry details - Can you please txt me my outstanding balance amont to above number so i can pay it today email address westvandercan@gmail.com phone number 0405453255 Preferred Contact method Phone"